# MySQL replace colum names instead of individual "as"

Tags: mysql

Is there any easier way of writing sql to replace all columns names with "schedule_" to make it easier to work with in PHP.

```
SELECT * FROM schedules

Array
(
    [schedule_id] => 9
    [schedule_datetime_from] => 2011-12-22 18:28:00
    [schedule_datetime_until] => 2011-12-22 22:28:00
    [schedule_capacity] => 89
    [schedule_amount] => 9.99
    [content_id] => 77
)
```

At the moment I end up doing:

```
$stmnt1 = "SELECT s.schedule_id as id, s.schedule_datetime_from as datetime_from, s.schedule_datetime_until as datetime_until, etc FROM schedules s";
```

Comment: Can you show the schema? If you have any indices, UNIQUE constraints, or Foreign Keys, you will have to account for those as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no other way to do this through SQL -- and really, why would you want to? It's not like you are typing in the query by hand each time.

What you *could* do is write PHP code that changes the array keys after each row has been read, but that's orders of magnitude worse as a solution. Just go with what you already have.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jon, but if you REALLY have to get this done I would recommend using the MySQL command line interface. However, you must also consider indices, UNIQUE constraints, and Foreign Keys. And, if you have any code which is expecting the non-prefixed versions of the columns you will end up breaking it, so be sure your code is updated as well.

Read up on ALTER TABLE  CHANGE via [MySQL docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/alter-table.html), the line you are looking for is: "You can rename a column using a CHANGE old_col_name new_col_name column_definition clause"